# React Native Search Bar onCancel method doesn't fire

Tags: react-native

react-native: 0.53.0

react-native-elements: 1.0.0-beta4,

When I use Search Bar component from React Native Elements library, I am unable to capture 'onCancel' property.  Code is provided below.

```
  <SearchBar
    lightTheme
    clearIcon
    platform={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios" : "android"}
    placeholder="Search..."
    returnKeyType='search'
    cancelButtonTitle="Cancel"
    onCancel        ={()=>{this.doSomething();}}
    onSubmitEditing ={()=>{this.handleSearch();}}
  />
```

Comment: you can use onClear method

Comment: onClear() is only called if I actually want to clear the Text in the search bar.  I just want capture when the user pushes 'cancel' next to the search bar component regardless if the content is cleared or not

Comment: I am able to debug the `onCancel`, what error are you facing specifically?

Comment: @PritishVaidya . I am not getting a error.  In my 'this.doSomething()' I simply just just write to console but no value is ever written.  I am on the 1.0.0-Beta 4 version but I see onCancel in the docs

Comment: Yea I am able to log it, using the same code, on pressing the `cancel` button. It would be great if you could make a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)

Comment: Im gonna try to update my my modules.  thank you for the feedback.  Just to clarify,  you are running 1.0.0-Beta 4 react-native-elements package correct?

Comment: can you share all part of code?
I think there is a problem in other part in js file.

Comment: Yes everything is the same @skrusetvt

Comment: @heltdev You want to see my whole file ?

Comment: yeah, I shared my simple search bar test project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude this, it was a syntax error.  =(
when I made the call

```
    onCancel={()=>{this.doSomething();}}
```

I wrapped it with the '{ }'.  It should of been

```
    onCancel={()=>this.viewHeader()}
```

I did want to point out though however that the calls :

```
    onFocus         ={()=>{this.hideHeader();}}
    onBlur          ={()=>{this.viewHeader();}}
```

are valid calls and it behaves properly.  I think this is due to implementation by React-Native-Elements.  The functions, onFocus() and onBlur() are explicitly written in the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/searchbar/SearchBar-ios.js).

```
onFocus = () => {
    this.props.onFocus();
    UIManager.configureNextLayoutAnimation && 
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    this.setState({ hasFocus: true });
};

onBlur = () => {
    this.props.onBlur();
    UIManager.configureNextLayoutAnimation && 
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    this.setState({ hasFocus: false });
};

onChangeText = text => {
    this.props.onChangeText(text);
    this.setState({ isEmpty: text === '' });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote simple script with snack and tested. it works.
https://snack.expo.io/r12AYAoiG

Please change platform to ios and test it on iOS emulator.

I hope it give you some hints.

Comment: Sorry I should of specified.  I am running on IOS

Comment: you need to change platform to ios from android and run it on iOS emulator.